# In Mobile Textarea apply XSS Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss, html-escape-characters

I have a simple Mobile Web HTML Form and within the TextArea a user can input any data.

I need to create a function that can apply XSS filter by not passing any HTML or Invalid XSS data to the server.

I am currently using a owasp recommended XSS Escape HTML like:

```
var data = document.getElementById(__fieldname__).innerHTML;
data = data.replace(/\<(.*?)DOCTYPE(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<html(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<\/html(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<script(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<\/script(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<style(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<\/style(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<body(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<\/body(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<form(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<\/form(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<iframe(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\<\/iframe(.*?)\>/ig, '')
            .replace(/\&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/\</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/\>/g, '&gt;')
            .replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/\'/g, '&#x27;')
            .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;');
 use data...
```

any suggestions or improvements?

Comment: You can not rely on clients only sending you “safe” data. This should be done server-side in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> You are validating data using javascript which is basically validate
>   data at client side and there are some cases if user blocking
>   javascript then user can easily bypass this so better option for this
>   kind of validation is to use server-side validation too.

Comment: I am using similar function on Server Side too.
Just wanted to escape it client side as its the first payload to be sent to the server.